# SerializationException when adding a Windows control to an Excel 2007 Worksheet

Tags: c#, user-controls, excel-2007, appdomain, excel-interop

I keep getting an exception when adding a control directly to a worksheet. The code is placed inside a form, and is not part of the ribbon.

Here is my code:

```
// using TExcel = Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel;
// MyGlobalsWrapper references the Globals object, which has been passed across an
// AppDomain barrier

Excel.Worksheet activeWorksheet = MyGlobalsWrapper.Application.ActiveSheet;
TExcel.Worksheet toolsSheet = MyGlobalsWrapper.Factory.GetVstoObject(activeWorksheet);
var range = activeWorksheet.Range["A1:F20"];

var button = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
button.Text = "HELLO!";
button.Visible = true;

// Both of these fail with the same exception

// Add manually (as the Range object might be the problem
toolsSheet.Controls.AddControl(button,10,10,button.Width,button.Height,id);

// Add using a range (which is more ideal for my usage)
toolsSheet.Controls.AddControl(button,range ,id);
```

The exception is as follows:

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException occurred
  Message=Type 'Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.ControlCollectionImpl' in Assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Implementation, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not marked as serializable.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
    Server stack trace: 
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.InternalGetSerializableMembers(RuntimeType type)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers(Type type, StreamingContext context)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitMemberInfo()
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter, SerializationBinder binder)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.Serialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter, SerializationBinder binder)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize(Object graph, Header[] inHeaders, __BinaryWriter serWriter, Boolean fCheck)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph, Header[] headers, Boolean fCheck)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSerializer.SerializeMessageParts(ArrayList argsToSerialize)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.SmuggledMethodReturnMessage..ctor(IMethodReturnMessage mrm)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.SmuggledMethodReturnMessage.SmuggleIfPossible(IMessage msg)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSink.DoDispatch(Byte[] reqStmBuff, SmuggledMethodCallMessage smuggledMcm, SmuggledMethodReturnMessage& smuggledMrm)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSink.DoTransitionDispatchCallback(Object[] args)
    Exception rethrown at [0]: 
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
       at Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Worksheet.get_Controls()
```

My references are as follows:

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
   v12 - CLR: v1.1.4322
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Extensions 
   v12 - CLR: 2.0.50727
Microsoft.Office.Tools
Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common
Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.v4.0.Utilities
Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel
Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.v4.0.Utilities
   v10 - CLR: 4.0.30919

I have tried wrapping it in a `System.Windows.Forms.UserControl`, but I have the same issue.

**Note:** I want to make use of Windows Controls, because I intend to embed a User Control into the sheet, rather than just a button. I was starting with a simple control and working up. So I need a solution that uses Windows Forms control (preferably a UserControl) rather than any of the controls provided by the Excel framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running this code in a separate AppDomain?

If you are then the ControlsCollection will need to be marshalled across the AppDomain barrier.  As with most marshalling this will be achieved by serialisation.

Is it possible to run this code in the main Excel AppDomain?

Comment: Yes - you are absolutely right! The control is being created in a seperate AppDomain, as I'm pre-empting the memory usage by this particular app. After running it in the main AppDomain, it is working perfectly. Thanks